# A bug of coroutine of boost1.53?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, bind, coroutine

I use coroutine of boost 1.53 and try the code from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine.html#coroutine.coroutine.calling_a_coroutine:

```
typedef boost::coroutines::coroutine< void() > coro_t;
void fn( coro_t::caller_type & ca, int j) {
  for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
    std::cout << "fn(): local variable i == " << i << std::endl;
    ca();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // bind parameter '7' to coroutine-fn
  coro_t c( boost::bind( fn, _1, 7) );

  std::cout << "main() starts coroutine c" << std::endl;

  while ( c)
  {
    std::cout << "main() calls coroutine c" << std::endl;
    // execution control is transferred to c
    c();
  }

  std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

```
fn(): local variable i == 0
main() starts coroutine c
main() calls coroutine c
fn(): local variable i == 1
main() calls coroutine c
fn(): local variable i == 2
main() calls coroutine c
fn(): local variable i == 3
main() calls coroutine c
fn(): local variable i == 4
main() calls coroutine c
fn(): local variable i == 5
main() calls coroutine c
fn(): local variable i == 6
main() calls coroutine c
Done
```

The output is different from the link in the first two.
Is it a Bug?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is in the first sentence of the documentation:

> The execution control is transferred to coroutine at *construction* (coroutine-function entered)

When you construct the coroutine, it calls it pretty much immediately, hence the first line gets printed before your message `main() starts coroutine c`.   The coroutine actually starts here:

```
    coro_t c( boost::bind( fn, _1, 7) );
```

I would argue that their example output is incorrect as compared to the example itself.  In fact, there's no code between the two `std::cout` calls in `main` other than `while (c)`, so I don't see how the output could *possibly* match the example.  I don't think testing the continuation predicate is supposed to start the coroutine.  Given the example after that first one, I suspect they meant to write:

```
    std::cout << "main() starts coroutine c" << std::endl;

    // bind parameter '7' to coroutine-fn
    coro_t c( boost::bind( fn, _1, 7) );
```

You can see in their next example that they call the constructor *after* the message from `main` and get the output you'd expect:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "main(): call coroutine c" << std::endl;
    coro_t c( fn, 7);

    int x = c.get();
    std::cout << "main(): transferred value: " << x << std::endl;

    x = c( 10).get();
    std::cout << "main(): transferred value: " << x << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

leads to:

```
output:
    main(): call coroutine c
    fn(): local variable i == 7
    main(): transferred value: 7
    fn(): local variable i == 10
    main(): transferred value: 10
    Done
```